# Where is JnlpDownloadServlet in JDK 7?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-7

According to Oracle's online documentation, JnlpDownloadServlet is still a part of Java 7: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html

But I just installed JDK 1.7.0, and neither jnlp-servlet.jar nor jardiff.jar appear anywhere in my Java home, at least on Windows.  I ran a search through every jar in the directory (using the excellent ack command-line utility) and none of them contain JnlpDownloadServlet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starting with Java 7 Update 2 the "Demos and Samples" were made into a separate download.

You can find the download link to the latest "Demos and Samples" listed here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
(Search on page for "samples").

You will find jnlp-servlet.jar, etc. therein:

jdk-7u6-windows-i586-demos.zip:/jdk1.7.0_06/sample/jnlp/servlet/jnlp-servlet.jar

Answer (score 4):

Oddly, the Mac version doesn't have it. Have to download the windows samples. Why different platforms should have different samples on the write-once run-anywhere platform is beyond me.