# Is it impossible to run Java Web Start application using "SDKMAN!"

Tags: java, java-web-start, sdkman

Hello I'm not familiar with Java. I'm trying to run Java Web Start (`javaws` command) using [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/) to use a Supermicro's legacy IPMI application.

It seems that Oracle Java 8 was able to run `javaws` but it is removed since Java 9. It also seems that SDKMAN! removed Oracle Java due to Oracle's licensing problem.

So I assume that there is no way to install `javaws` using SDKMAN! currently and we have to install the old Oracle's Java 8 manually out of SDKMAN!. It this right assumption? Thank you.

Comment: j9 did not remove javaws. j9 _removed_ browser-plugin applets, but only _deprecated_ appletviewer and webstart; j11 removed those. However, Oracle 9 and 10 are now past EOL and unsupported, as well as being under the new license. _Current_ Oracle 8 (after spring 2019) is also under the new license. You don't say what OS you are on, but at least RedHat/CentOS and Debian/Ubuntu offer openjdk-8 (_or_ newer) plus as a separate package icedtea, which is asserted to be technically the same as Oracle applet.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation and to clear my understanding. Sorry for lacking the information and actually I'm using Ubuntu desktop 20.04. I didn't know icedtea and this package (`icedtea-netx` package for Ubuntu 20.04) has `javaws` binary. It enables me to run jnlp binary. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23925666/1204782

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaWebStart has been developed closed source by Oracle and therefore is only part of the Oracle JDK. Since Oracle stopped JavaWebStart it is even in the Oracle JDK not provided for Java 11+.

In general you have 3 ways you can go:

- Use an old Java 8 build from Oracle that does not has fixes for security issues of the last 18 month
- Buy support for Java 8 at Oracle and use an actual build of the Oracle JDK version. 8
- Install AdoptOpenJDK 8 LTS version on windows and select to use IcedTea-Web in the installer
- Use [OpenWebstart](https://openwebstart.com) in combination with any Java 8 or Java 11 JRE / JDK. That can provided by SDKMAN for example

Comment: I didn't know OpenWebstart but it seems to be the best option for me. It is GPLv2 licensed + can be used with SDKMAN provided Java. Thank you.

Comment: too bad that for linux, openwebstart only offers package for ubuntu.